# What's the best image compressing software for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, image-processing

I need an application I can use to compress pictures without losing the quality.

I've heard about Trimage and GIMP.

Comment: Is your goal to be able to immediately view the images (ie: no external compression)?  `webp` has a lossless mode.  Could you benefit from [Adam7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam7_algorithm)?

Answer (score 2):

png is the way to go. In very specific cases, you get a better lossless compression by saving the file as a bmp and then compressing it using 7zip, but this makes it impossible to view them with normal image viewer software or to edit them with normal image editing software.

You will still be able to save a tiny, tiny amount of storage space by compressing png images with 7zip, but it's not worth the unacceptability that comes with it.

If you first use a lossy compression (like jpeg) and then a lossless compression (like png), not only will you have the same quality like the jpeg image (which lost quality in respect to the original image) and use more storage space than the jpeg image, the use of storage space will also be higher than if you took the original image directly and converted it to png. This is generally true, even for using the same lossy compression over and over again: If you do so, not only will the quality (of course) decrease every single time, you also will use more and more storage space. So make sure to convert the original image to png, not images which are currently stored as jpegs. Do, however, store images which used to be stored as jpegs as png, after you edited them, to avoid further loss of quality and making the storage space use when eventually saving them as pngs even worse.

You convert a lot of images to png using the command

```
mogrify -format png /your/path/*.jpg
```

or

```
mogrify -format png /your/path/*.jpeg
```

depending on which file extension the images have.

If you want to move the converted images somewhere else, use

```
mv /original/path/*.png /new/path
```

, and if you want to just delete the old ones, use

```
rm /your/path/*.jpg
```

or

```
rm /your/path/*.jpeg
```

You will be able to store individual images as pngs in about every graphics program (like gimp).

Comment: @Iwobe Aigboje Did this answer your question?

Comment: I don't think so. I just needed an application to compress my images from MB to kb. So they can load faster. I need them for Web Development

Comment: @IwobeAigboje That's not possible with lossless compression. Then you need to use jpeg.